# Google Chrome is stuck. How to fix that?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

My Google Chrome is always stuck. If I resize the window or open full screen it works again for another few seconds, and then it's stuck again. What could it be?

It seems that it's stuck when I hover on objects on the client side that probably run java script or Ajax. For instance, if it's open on my Gmail, it's stuck when I hover on the "Inbox" button.

I tried to remove all extensions. I removed (uninstalled) the application and then installed again. It does not help.

I'm running Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 1):

Try going to the address `chrome://flags/` and click the "reset all to default" button on the right side. When prompted, restart the browser.

Comment: To make this a really great answer, it might be worth mentioning what "reset all to default" does, so that it's clear what the consequences of that action is...

Comment: I tried this, but the problem still occurs ... :(

Comment: tried this, but of no use..

Answer (score 0):

try clearing your chrome user settings
start ->run-> and put the following into the dialog
%appdata%
or type that into windows explorer

you should be able to find a folder for chrome under the google folder which you can rename and see if that helps

or create a newuser in windows to see if the problem is in your profile

Comment: I created a new user. Same problem still occurs ... :(

Comment: If you created a new windows user and that didn't work, you can try a portable version of chrome from portableapps.com, see if it's an issue with other software on your machine. Google Chrome Portable will run as much as possible standalone. If it works my recommendation would be to open a trouble ticket with google. Hopefully someone else might have suggestions. I'll update my comments if anything else occurs to me, but I think we're pretty stuck. Also you could try creating a new user from inside the browser settings menu!

Comment: Thank you @stvie. I installed the portable version but it's just the same ... :( BTW I figured now that it's just the same with FireFox. Do not know why and how to solve this.

Comment: maybe a bit too obvious, but have you tried to scan for viruses?

Answer (score 0):

In windows 7 the "auto proxy detection" is turned on in Internet Options in the control panel.  Turn it off and everything is groovy :)

Comment: How are IE settings supposed to affect Chrome?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev IE Settings actually tie in to 'Internet Settings' which does tie in to other browsers. If you go in to Control Panel and dig around you'll see that it's not explicitly dealing with IE.